# Following on from vs Following up on

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I just want to understand the difference between ***"Following up on & Following on from"***. Is it exactly the same meaning?

Here you have an example:

> - Following on from your email below
> - Following up on your email below

Is there any difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"To follow on from something" means **to happen after something, and often as the next part or stage of it** ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/follow-on-from#:%7E:text=(follow%20on%20from%20something)%20to,part%20or%20stage%20of%20it)):

> - ***Following on from*** last year’s success, we’ll be offering other similar
>   courses.
> - What I’m going to say ***follows on from*** what Elizabeth was
>   saying.

"To follow up on something" means ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow%20up%20on%20%28something%29#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20follow%20up%20on%20(something),-chiefly%20US&text=1%20%3A%20to%20try%20to%20get,follow%20up%20on%20his%20complaints.)) ***to do something in response to (something) : to take appropriate action about (something)***

> He says that the police failed to ***follow up on*** his complaints.

So, ***Following on from your email below*** would mean that you are continuing a chain of meaning or information, whereas ***Following up on your email below*** would mean that you are simply responding to that email.